# Output each mongodb record to an html table

Tags: php, mongodb, crud, php-mongodb

I'm building an app which pulls records from a MongoDB. I've built the thead>tr>th as follows:

```php
    // building table head with keys
    $cursor = $collection->find();
    $array = iterator_to_array($cursor);
    $keys = array();
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            foreach ($v as $a => $b) {
                    $keys[] = $a;
            }
    }
    $keys = array_values(array_unique($keys));
    // assuming first key is MongoID so skipping it
    foreach (array_slice($keys,1) as $key => $value) {
        echo "<th>" . $value . "</th>";
    }
```

This gives me:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>address</th>
        <th>city</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

This works very well, it grabs all the keys and builds the table head. I don't have to specify anything and the thead is built dynamically from the data. The part I'm unable to figure out is building all of the tr>td's

I can easily grab the info and build it like this:

```php
$cursor = $collection->find();
$cursor_count = $cursor->count();
    foreach ($cursor as $venue) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $venue['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $venue['address'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $venue['city'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Doing so requires me to modify my php every time I add a new field. How can I build the tr>td's automagically based on the data from mongodb like I am with the thead?

My data looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "Some Venue",
  "address": "1234 Anywhere Dr.",
  "city": "Some City"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try to use second foreach as below

```
$cursor = $collection->find();
$cursor_count = $cursor->count();
    foreach ($cursor as $venue) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach (array_slice($keys,1) as $key => $value) {
           echo "<td>" . $venue[$value] . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
```

Comment: This won't be valid HTML should the rows have different fields in some documents. Also field names would look odd here especially if the first row omits from fields from other rows. Basically this will, in most cases, create a malformed table for schemaless rows.